# Cannot play internet stations with media player (Lubuntu 13.04)

Tags: lubuntu, vlc, music-player

I am able to play flash videos now, but not internet music.

I get the following error message:

```
Could not load mplayerplug-in is now gecko-mediaplayer 1.0.8.
```

I installed VLC with the command `sudo apt-get install vlc browser-plugin-vlc` but I still could not get anything working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install gecko-mediaplayer
```

Comment: I tried the above command but I still can't play internet music.  I get the message, "gecko-mediaplayer is already the newest version." when I run the command.

Comment: Well I found my open tabs for both players.  I tried opening the channel to play the music with each player opened, but I still get the message "Could not load mplayerplug-in is now gecko-mediaplayer 1.0.8."  So that's not doing the trick.